env variables give undefined in production server in node js
I am working on a Node.js project that works perfectly on both my local and development servers. However, after moving the project to a live server, I am encountering an issue where environment variable values are coming up as undefined.
I have installed the dotenv package and included the following line in my code:
require('dotenv').config();
Despite this, the environment variables are still undefined on the live server. I have verified that the .env file is present in the root directory of my project on the live server.
What steps can I take to resolve this issue and ensure that environment variables are properly loaded on the live server?
I am running node with pm2 on live server.
I tried to change require to import but then I could get any response.
Also tried below command but still undefined
pm2 restart www --update-env 


Have you tried e.g. console.log(process.env.SOMETHING) where you know for a fact SOMETHING is in the .env file?

@AKX yeah i tried it but still undefined. One thing i forgot to tell you that i move .env file from dev to production. Shall i create it again?
